# How to add number assigned as array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have that script that is supposed to read data from two txt files and add them. For that matter I have used array.

I can read the data but there is a problem with the addition.

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
declare -a data1
while read data1
do
data1[$n]=$data1
n=$(( n+1 ))
done <analysisSBM105.out
echo ${data1[1]}
echo ${data1[2]}
echo ${data1[3]}
echo ${data1[4]}

m=1
declare -a data2
while read data2
do
data2[$m]=$data2
m=$(( m+1 ))
done <analysisSBM105.out
echo ${data2[1]}
echo ${data2[2]}
echo ${data2[3]}
echo ${data2[4]}

i=1
declare -a dataAll
while [ $i -le 4 ];
do
${dataAll[$i]}= $( ${data1[$i]}+${data2[$i]} )


i=$(( i+1 ))

done

echo ${dataAll[1]}
echo ${dataAll[2]}
echo ${dataAll[3]}
echo ${dataAll[4]}
```

Instead of `${dataAll[$i]}= $( ${data1[$i]}+${data2[$i]} )`, I have also used  `'expr ${data1[$i]}+${data2[$i]}'`
The analysisSBM105.out file has the following

```
6436
4167
1933
164
172
```

But still it doesn't work. The error is

```
6436
4167
1933
164
6436
4167
1933
164
Report105.sh: line 35: dataAll[1]: command not found
Report105.sh: line 35: dataAll[2]: command not found
Report105.sh: line 35: dataAll[3]: command not found
Report105.sh: line 35: dataAll[4]: command not found
```

Desired output is the following.

```
12872
8334
3866
328
344
```

Comment: what is going on in `${dataAll[$i]}= $( ${data1[$i]}+${data2[$i]} )`? You properly did `data2[$m]=$data2` - so just follow the convention, no?

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to sum them up and store it in array dataAll[$i]. And ```data2[$m]=$data2``` has worked.

Comment: instead of `${dataAll[$i]}= $( ${data1[$i]}+${data2[$i]} )` ... try `dataAll[$i]=$(( ${data1[$i]}+${data2[$i]} ))`

Comment: @markp-fuso Result is  ```  Report105.sh: line 35: dataAll[1]: command not found  ```

Comment: Remove the space after and before `=`. It's `dataAll[$i]=$((` _not_ `dataAll[$i] =$((`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks. That totally works.

Comment: It's not strictly wrong, but the way you're treating `data1` and `data2` sometimes as simple variables and sometimes as arrays disturbs me. For example, when you use `read data1` you're treating `data1` as if it was a simple variable (it actually reads into `data1[0]`), and then you copy that simple value into an array element with `data1[$n]=$data1` (which is equivalent to `data1[$n]=${data1[0]}` -- copying the value from element [0] to where it actually belongs). IMO it'd be better to either use a different plain variable or read directly to the right place with `read data1[$n]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is space aware. Variable assignment has a `=` character with *no* spaces before nor after it.

```
${dataAll[$i]}= $( ${data1[$i]}+${data2[$i]} )
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   - command to run
                ^^                           ^ - command substitution, runs command inside
               ^                               - space after `=` - it's not assignment
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                - runs a command named that after expansion
```

while I guess you wanted to do:

```
dataAll[i]=$(( data1[i] + data2[i] ))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    - expression to calculate, `${..}` is not needed
           ^^^                     ^^ - arithemtic expansion   
          ^                           - no spaces around =
^^^^^^^^^^                            - variable name
```

Notes:

- `declare -a array` is not needed. You can just use `dataAll[0]=something` straight away.
- it's easier to write `for ((i=0;i<4;++i))` then `i=0;while [ "$i" -le 4 ]; do something; i=$((i+1)); done`. Also you may `for i in $(seq 4)`
- Indent your code properly.
- Use http://shellcheck.net to check your code
- The `array[<here>]` - the `<here>` part runs as a arithmetic expression, that means that variables are automatically expanded. `dataAll[$i]` is equal to `dataAll[i]`. The same happens inside `$((..))` - `$(( ${dataAll[$i]} ))` is equal to `$(( dataAll[$i] ))` or just `$(( dataAll[i] ))`
- Print array on separate newlines with just `printf "%s\n" "${dataAll[@]}"`.
- You may want to rewrite it in `awk` for speed and efficiency